# For iOS developers, are GM releases eligible for OTA updates on point releases?

Tags: ios, developer-program

The iOS 7 betas are the first set of OS betas I've been through as a member of the Developer Program. Manually installing the beta releases is one thing, but now that a GM has been released will the 7.0.1 release be available to the GM build installed as an OTA update? Or will I have to install that from the image manually, and then get OTA updates for version 7.0.2 and onward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Excluding any major issues, the GM release for developers is the same as the first release to the public. Future point releases can be updated over-the-air rather than through a manual image install.